# tomcat deploy from netbeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans, tomcat7, netbeans-7.1

I write my first service in Netbeans 7.1.1 and can`t deploy it on Tomcat 7 server.

```
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at /home/likewise-open/PROMWAD/alexandr.kurkin/NetBeansProjects/HelloWs1/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext1698562612061154650.xml&war=file:/home/likewise-open/PROMWAD/alexandr.kurkin/NetBeansProjects/HelloWs1/build/web/
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext1698562612061154650.xml&war=file:/home/likewise-open/PROMWAD/alexandr.kurkin/NetBeansProjects/HelloWs1/build/web/
/home/likewise-open/PROMWAD/alexandr.kurkin/NetBeansProjects/HelloWs1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:729: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 44 seconds)
```

Tomcat`s log is without errors.

Deploy stopped in this line in build-impl.xml

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will have to reinstall **NetBeans**. While installation NetBeans will show you both Glassfish & Tomcat as server option. You will have to select Tomcat as server. Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.
Please note that adding server externally in NetBeans causes problems sometime.

Comment: Thank you for the way out. But it is still unclear why does not work external Tomcat.

Comment: hey alain i m not saying that u can't add externally tomcat into net bean but i try to say that it give problem when u missed some points to correct ......

Answer (score 3):

*Netbeans* can work with external *Tomcat*. But sometimes when you change of netbeans version or *tomcat* version, the configuration file get corrupted (`build-impl.xml`). So don't reinstall *Netbeans* the easiest way is to create a new clean project and copy/paste the source. I've encountered this kind of error many times (at least one project after each updates...) so I think it will work.

Comment: Doesn't help with clean project :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that, in tomcat/conf/server.xml, the URIEncoding is correct. 
NetBeans put the context.xml in C:\Users\your-name\AppData\Local\Temp, so if your name is Chinese or ..., tomcat may not find the context.xml and fail to deploy your web-app.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               URIEncoding="utf-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```